# In RobotFramework, how can we use value of one test suite into another test suite in linux?

Tags: python, linux, robotframework

i want to pick a value from one test suite and use it into other test suite in robotframework.Can anyone explain how to do that through keywords and please may i know the different ways to perfrom that operation?

Comment: Hii. Welcome to SO. Better to write your approach first.

Comment: i am trying to create a variable in variables section and stroing the value from the test suite in it and then trying to use in into other test suite but it is not working

Comment: Next time show your attemts, how you try to achieve something and how exactly _it's not working_. Read also [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 4):

Keyword [Set Global Variable](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Set%20Global%20Variable) is what you need:

```
Set Global Variable     ${global}      Hello, world!
```

Now you can access `${global}` in any test suite.

PS. Enjoy reading [Robot Framework User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/#user-guide).